# Bundle install failed due to unf_ext (0.0.5) gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundle-install

I have installed ruby 1.9.3p327 & rails 3.2.8 using rvm on centos 6.3. But while doing bundle install for a particular project folder, the process fails in between when it tries to install gem unf_ext 0.0.5 and throws following error,

Installing unf_ext (0.0.5) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/home/rradmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb -fPIC
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling unf.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/vector:61,
from unf/normalizer.hh:4,
from unf.cc:1:
.....
....
...
```

Gem files will remain installed in /home/rradmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@r32/gems/unf_ext-0.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rradmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@r32/gems/unf_ext-0.0.5/ext/unf_ext/gem_make.out

> An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.5), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.5'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

I also tried to install unf_ext separately as mentioned above, but got the same error.
I have referred https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/135, but still not able to solve the problem. Please let me know proper way to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Suman. But I resolved the issue by installing **libstdc++-devel** using yum install gcc-g++  libstdc++-devel.

Answer (score 21):

On Ubuntu I only needed to do

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

to fix this.

(for the record I'm on a freshly-built Ubuntu 12.10 Server X64)

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you don't have supporting libraries to compile the gem try to install the following packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core     zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison
```

then do a bundle install

Comment: Thanks Suman. 
I am using centos 6.3 and i have already used

rvmsudo yum install -y gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison iconv-devel

for getting the supporting libraries. Still i tried your command using yum but lot of libraries are missing. 

Does this command differs based on OS ?

Comment: yes it differs you need to find appropriate packages in centos 6.3 try to install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev packages it may fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by installing **libstdc++-devel** using `yum install gcc-c++  libstdc++-devel`