# Getting a error when trying to add the stripe gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stripe-payments

I am trying to install the stripe gem and I'm getting this error

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151005-1267-af6sn6.rb extconf.rb checking for main() in
>   -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. 
>   Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby
>     --with-static-libstdc++     --without-static-libstdc++  --with-stdc++lib
>     --without-stdc++lib
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in
>   `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
>   (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.   from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in`
>   try_link0'   from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in
>   `try_link'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:714:in`
>   try_func'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:944:in
>   `block in have_library'   from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:889:in`
>   block in checking_for'   from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in
>   `block (2 levels) in postpone'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in`
>   open'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in
>   `block in postpone'   from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in`
>   open'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in
>   `postpone'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:888:in`
>   checking_for'    from
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:939:in
>   `have_library'    from extconf.rb:6:in`'
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/Fysh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.0.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.1), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.1'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Comment: It looks like you have some resources there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835950/bundle-install-failed-due-to-unf-ext-0-0-5-gem

Please try these before

Comment: Try `rvm requirements`. And did you install CommandLine Development Tools?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: yes CommandLine Development Tools are installed

Answer (score 0):

Solved had an xcode update after I updated it worked.

Comment: I would highly recommend you use a tool to help you manage your Ruby, such as [rvm](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).